# How to remove <td> or </td> with sed?

Tags: sed

I am successfully using:

```
s/^[[:space:]]*<[/]*tr.*>//
```

to change any lines starting with `<tr>` or `</tr>`, removing those tags.

However when I try using

```
s/^[[:space:]]*<[/]*td.*>//
```

to remove `<td>` or `</td>`s, it only removes `<td>`s, not the `</td>`s

Current output:

```
${url_reset}</td>
</td>

open</td>
${url_3_step_minimal_foundation}</td>
</td>

assertVisible</td>
${css_zip_code}</td>
</td>
```

Comment: Secondary I'll change `/` delimiter for some else

Comment: sometimes they are on the same line, sometimes not

Comment: `g` would have no effect here as the regex is anchored. OP, you do realise your post actually explains why it doesn't work ? _"I am successfully using... to change any lines starting with..."_

Comment: `^[[:space:]]` mean started frof the begining of the line with possible `spaces` in between.

Comment: I like the delimiter change idea but `s%<[/]*td>%%` also isn't working - removes `<td>`s but not `</td>`s

Comment: You have to show input data and full sed line because your script successfully removes `</td>` from your output example.

Comment: I also tried `s%<.?*td>%%` but it left the `<td>`s

Comment: The `?` should be escaped `s%<.\?*td>%%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
sed 's/<[/]*td.*>//' file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
s%</*td.*>%%
```

was one approach that also worked avoid avoided the need for the `[\]`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's#^[[:space:]]*</\{0,1\}td.*>##'
```

maybe more secure

```
sed 's#^[[:space:]]*</\{0,1\}td[^>]*>##'
```

- use of another separator (avoiding escape of `/`)
- allow maximum 1 `/` after `<` before `td`
- in secure version, it stop at first `>` after `td`

Answer (score -1):

You can also try 
`sed 's/<\/\?[^>]\+>//g'`

this will remove anything that has a tag in it

Comment: But that was not the question.